# Using the EM algorithm on a Latent Factor Model (Collaborative Filtering)

Tags: missing-data, expectation-maximization, recommender-system

I have a pretty straightforward question. I have a database of user/item ratings from which I've built a latent factor model of the form:
$$R_{u,i} = \alpha + \beta_i + \beta_u + \gamma_i * \gamma_u$$
Nothing too complicated yet. $\alpha$ is a global offset, $\beta_i$ is an item-specific bias, $\beta_u$ is a user-specific bias, and $\gamma_i$ and $\gamma_u$ are $k$-dimensional latent representations of each item and user respectively.

Now, I have item-specific information that I also want to use in my model:
$$R_{u,i} = \alpha + \beta_i + \beta_u + (\gamma_i + \sum_{a\in A(i)} (\rho_a)) * \gamma_u$$
where $\rho_a$ refers to a $k$-dimensional parameter vector corresponding to a binary feature about item $i$. For example, if my data is user/item ratings for a movie, each element in $A(i)$ might refer to membership of the movie in a particular genre (e.g. action, sci-fi).

I've built a system so far that handles everything well, up to this point. Where it gets complicated is that there is missing genre information for some (but not all) movies. In the above model, I simply removed movies that lacked this information.

But now, I want to infer the genres for the movies that lack genre information. To that end, I've chosen to use the EM algorithm to fill in the missing information. I'm familiar with EM algorithm in other use cases (e.g. in Bayesian networks) but I've never used them in this case.

Here's what I do understand:

1) Intuitively, I know in the E-Step I'm going to want to infer the probability that each movie without genre information belongs to a specific genre. So the number of variables I need to infer is ($m*n$), where $m$ is the number of movies without genres and $n$ is the number of genres.

2) In the M-step, I'm going to update my parameters. This step should be pretty similar to the above example with complete information, except it relies on E-step estimates for the missing data's genre information.

My questions are:

1) When it comes to the M-step, it seems pretty computationally intensive to have to optimize my entire latent factor model every iteration of the EM algorithm. Am I missing something there?

2) When it comes to the E-step, how exactly should I model it? This step in particular I'm pretty lost on. I know on a high level what I want to do, but mathematically I'm pretty lost.

Any and all advice would be appreciated!